# Recommended convention / coding style

Tags: bash, ksh

I am in a process of refactoring some unix shell scripts
and find many inconsistencies and different styles in our code

For example:

```
somevar="${item1},${item2}"
somevar=${item1}","${item2}
somevar="$item1,$item2"
```

Is there a coding style guide for unix shell scripts? or a formatter like clang-format for C++

**[Edit]** Please note I am not asking for personal style preferences or personal opinion! I am looking for an industry standard document, a widely used style guide or a popular tool.

Comment: Not sure why this question is opinion-based? I specifically asked for a standard coding style guide, convention and formatting tool. I didn't ask for an opinion or personal taste for the right format.

Comment: "asked for a standard coding style guide, convention and formatting tool" -> It seems like your questions turns from *opinion based* to *off-topic*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked in a few companies that have their own style guides but most now use Google's style guide.  If you don't have a home grown style guide then Google's is good and is published here: https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml

I personally check my shell scripts with the shellcheck plugin for vim but it's available on the web and for other editors.  You can use it and get the downloads here: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2):

Since [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) won't happen in the context of a variable assignment you could just use:

```
somevar=${item1},${item2}
```

I personally prefer to use

```
somevar="${item1},${item2}"
```

The quotes doesn't hurt and - imo - increase readability.

---

About `${var}` vs. `$var`. That matters when the variable name may contain an underscore, like `"$foo_bar"`. What does it mean? The variable `$foo` plus the literal string `_bar`? Or the expansion of the variable `$foo_bar`? I would consequently use `${var}` to avoid such situations.

Comment: For that reason I would only use curly braces where needed, because it then raises awareness. It saves keystrokes, especially on continental keyboards, where we need Alt-Gr + (7,0) to create them. :) . So I use somevar="$item1,$item2" where sufficient.

Comment: Start to use them consequently and you'll get addicted.